# Bug Problems With Swift and XCode

Tags: swift, ios10

Help, I am coding this game, and I keep getting an error that says:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Example:

[image: (Error Image)]

Everything has worked normally until I added code for the trump coin image and the label that says 'Score:'

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//DEFINING VARIABLES
var gameIsRunning = false
var paused = false

var totalCoins = 0
var totalScore = 0
var gameCoins = 0
var gameScore = 0

@IBOutlet var titleCoinsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var titleScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var titleTrumpCoin: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var titleScoreRun: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var gameTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var pauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var pauseView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var resumeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var optionsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var tutorialButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var rateApp: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var quitButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var tutorialBackButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var tutorialView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var titleOptions: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var titleTutorial: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var optionsView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var optionsBack: UIButton!





//WHEN GAME LOADS WHAT TO DO
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gameIsRunning = false

    pauseButton.isHidden = true
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    pauseButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    pauseButton.alpha = 0.75

    pauseView.isHidden = true
    pauseView.layer.cornerRadius = 20

    tutorialView.isHidden = true

    resumeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    optionsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    tutorialButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    rateApp.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    quitButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    tutorialBackButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    optionsView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    optionsBack.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    optionsView.isHidden = true

    titleCoinsLabel.text = String(totalCoins)

}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





//STARTING GAME
@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if gameIsRunning == false {

        gameIsRunning = true

        titleCoinsLabel.isHidden = true
        titleScoreLabel.isHidden = true

        playButton.isHidden = true
        playButton.isEnabled = false

        gameTitle.isHidden = true
        gameTitle.isEnabled = false

        pauseButton.isHidden = false
        pauseButton.isEnabled = true

        titleTutorial.isHidden = true
        titleTutorial.isEnabled = false

        titleOptions.isHidden = true
        titleOptions.isEnabled = false

        titleScoreRun.isHidden = true
        titleTrumpCoin.isHidden = true

        //NOT DEFINED YET
        runGame()

    }

}


//PAUSE
@IBAction func pauseGame(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    paused = true

    pauseView.isHidden = false

}

//RESUME
@IBAction func resumeGame(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    paused = false

    pauseView.isHidden = true

}

//VIEW OPTIONS
@IBAction func optionsView(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    optionsView.isHidden = false

    pauseView.isHidden = true

}

@IBAction func titleOptionsView(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    optionsView.isHidden = false

}

//BACK FROM OPTIONS
@IBAction func optionsBack(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    optionsView.isHidden = true

    if (paused == true) {

        pauseView.isHidden = false

    } else {

        pauseView.isHidden = true

    }

}

//OPTIONS TWEAKS
@IBAction func gameVolumeSlider(_ sender: AnyObject) {



}

@IBAction func musicVolumeSlider(_ sender: AnyObject) {



}

//VIEW TUTORIAL
@IBAction func tutorialView(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    pauseView.isHidden = true
    tutorialView.isHidden = false

}

@IBAction func titleTutorial(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    tutorialView.isHidden = false

}

//BACK FROM TUTORIAL
@IBAction func backTutorial(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    tutorialView.isHidden = true

    if (paused == true) {

        pauseView.isHidden = false

    } else {

        pauseView.isHidden = true

    }

}


//RATE APP
@IBAction func rateApp(_ sender: AnyObject) {



}

//QUIT GAME
@IBAction func quitGame(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    titleScoreLabel.isHidden = false
    titleCoinsLabel.isHidden = false

    pauseButton.isHidden = true
    pauseView.isHidden = true

    gameTitle.isHidden = false
    gameTitle.isEnabled = true
    playButton.isHidden = false
    playButton.isEnabled = true

    titleTutorial.isHidden = false
    titleTutorial.isEnabled = true

    titleOptions.isHidden = false
    titleOptions.isEnabled = true
    titleScoreRun.isHidden = true

    titleScoreRun.isHidden = false
    titleTrumpCoin.isHidden = false

    titleScoreLabel.text = String(gameScore)
    titleCoinsLabel.text = String(totalCoins)

    totalScore = totalScore + gameScore
    gameScore = 0
    totalCoins = totalCoins + gameCoins
    gameCoins = 0

}




//RECOGNIZING SWIPES
@IBAction func swipeRight(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if (gameIsRunning == true) {



    }

}

@IBAction func swipeLeft(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if (gameIsRunning == true) {



    }


}

@IBAction func press(_ sender: AnyObject) {



}




//FUNCTIONS TO RUN GAME
func runGame() {



}

}
```

Comment: Try to only post the code that is relevant to the bug. If you are not sure what code is relevant, try and at least narrow it down because right now there is just too much.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked! I really should have seen that. Lol

Comment: @Rob lol how do I mark an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you have not hooked up the `titleScoreLabel` outlet correctly. Double check that in Interface Builder.